# Des equivalents de "norm violators" ?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

J’en ai trouvé deux : 
– des violateurs de normes 
– des transgresseurs de normes

En connaissez-vous d’autres qui seraient un peu plus courants ?

Comment: peut-être *hors-norme* ?

Comment: "violateurs de normes" sounds very weird to my french ears. "transgresseurs de normes" is good, and depending on the context you may also try "disruptif", "iconoclaste", "qui fait bouger les lignes", "transgressif", "irrévérent"...

Answer (score 6):

En français on parle de la « déviance » pour désigner tout comportement de **transgression des normes sociales**.  L'adjectif *déviant* peut être substantivé :

> Tous les individus ne voient pas dans le **déviant** une figure sociale normale; beaucoup continuent à mettre l'accent sur ce qui sépare l'individu qui transgresse les normes, de celui qui les respecte. (*[Normes et déviances](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N9LAPWS2J8YC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22dans%20le%20d%C3%A9viant%20une%20figure%20sociale%20normale;%20beaucoup%20continuent%20%C3%A0%20mettre%20l%27accent%20sur%20ce%20qui%20s%C3%A9pare%20l%27individu%20qui%20transgresse%20les%20normes,%20de%20celui%20qui%20les%20respecte.%22&source=bl&ots=tMSZYm8BwW&sig=8JhoOjO4EijPjmr0VWzJJIRsE9M&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSi5fC54rWAhVELFAKHfT2Cc0Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22dans%20le%20d%C3%A9viant%20une%20figure%20sociale%20normale%3B%20beaucoup%20continuent%20%C3%A0%20mettre%20l%27accent%20sur%20ce%20qui%20s%C3%A9pare%20l%27individu%20qui%20transgresse%20les%20normes%2C%20de%20celui%20qui%20les%20respecte.%22&f=false)*, Véronique Pillon, 2003)

Il est plus courant de parler des « individus (gens, ceux...) qui adoptent des comportements déviants »  ou « qui transgressent les normes » que de « déviants » ou de « transgresseurs de normes ».

Quant à  « violateur de norme » ce n'est quasiment pas utilisé.

Comment: Bien vu, merci Laure!

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

> Marginal (noun/adj)
>   Anticonformiste (noun/adj)

Dans une moindre mesure

> Asocial, anti-social, misanthrope (noun/adj)
>   Contestataire (noun/adj)

### Explication

La recherche Google n'a pas donné d'article fiable pour servir de définition de base à *norm violator*. Si vous en avez à disposition, veuillez la partager.

Cependant, dans les différents forums/sites qui en parlent, des éléments reviennent suffisament régulièrement pour pouvoir en tirer une définition.

Tout d'abord *norm*, c'est exactement la même norme qu'en français. Ce n'est pas une loi, l'enfreindre n'est pénalement ou juridiquement pas répréhensible, mais elle est suivie quasiment uniformément par la société, ce qui fait de l'anormal l'exception. Il est à préciser qu'implicitement, toutes les normes auxquelles il est fait référence sont les normes sociales/morales (rien à voir avec les normes européennes pour le calibre des bananes e.g.)

Le *norm violator* est une personne qui ne respecte pas ces normes morales ou sociales, sciemment ou non. Il existe déjà des mots pour exprimer de telles personnes en français :
les **marginaux** et les **anti-conformistes**.
On peut, dans certains cas, parler de **politiquement incorrect** (adj) quand une personne a des propos délibérément choquants pour une tranche de la société, notamment le monde médiatique, sans pour autant que cela soit explicitement insultant ou illégal.

Comment: merci pour ta réponse, je pense qu'à notre époque les mots "marginaux" ou "anti-conformistes" ont perdu leur sens original (du moins celui que je cherche). A notre epoque un anti-conformiste peut être conformiste. Pour te donner une idée du mot et sens que je recherche il faudrait plutot voir le (véritable) "violeur de norme" de notre époque chez un "l'islamiste radical", ou "le nazi" (ils ne sont pas  du tout accepté parce qu'ils violent les normes).

Answer (score 2):

*Transgresseur* est le terme correct. Il n'y a pas de synonymes "un peu plus courants" parce qu'il n'y a pas vraiment de synonymes. La raison pour laquelle on ne rencontre pas *transgresseur* très souvent, c'est tout simplement qu'en dehors des écrits spécialisés, ce concept est généralement exprimé sous la forme de l'adjectif *transgressif* plutôt que du nom.

Answer (score 1):

The word délinquant means people that don't follow the rules, they violate them.

Comment: Un délinquant transgresse la norme mais tous ceux qui transgressent la norme sociale ne sont pas des délinquants. Un délinquant est en infraction avec la loi. On peut transgresser les normes sociales sans que ce soit un délit pénal.

Comment: @Laure Votre propos est juste. Par ailleurs la question ne précise aucun contexte et ne définit même pas le sens en anglais ni ne discute du domaine de la sociologie. D'un point vue lexical la réponse est intéressante à mon avis, avec les nuances dont vous traitez. [_Contrevenant_](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870241), dans la même veine. Merci !

Comment: Laure le mot anglais (du moins dans la litterature qui m'interresse) se rapproche plus de délinquant que du marginal (cf mon comment à Charly)